# Settings child.frame = parent.bounds?

Tags: ios, uiview, frame, bounds

Is it logically valid to do this:

```
child.frame = parent.bounds
```

Let's say I want add new CALayer as view's default layer sublayer, and I want that new CALayer to be positioned at (0,0) and have exactly the same size as it's parent. Then I would write this:

```
self.customSublayer.frame = self.view.layer.bounds;
```

I think this should work without problems in any scenario, but I want other opinions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the standard way to do it, i dont think you would need any other options